# python - using selenium chromedriver library to find link by element in website data

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to target this link with `find_element_by_class_name()`

```
<div class="searchResult-gridItem">
   <div class="searchResult" data-test="searchResult" role="none" tabindex="-1">
      <a data-testid="vehicle-card-link-box" href="/us/en/car-rental/united-states/hillside- 
      nj/tesla/model-3/802284?searchId=g0WoIMHS" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="css- 
      8ydh9n-VehicleCardLinkBox/div>
</div>
```

the link I'm trying to target is `/us/en/car-rental/united-states/hillside-nj/tesla/model-3/802284?searchId=g0WoIMHS` in the above.

I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'PATH\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(5)
browser.get('https://turo.com/us/en/search?country=US&defaultZoomLevel=11&delivery=false&endDate=09%2F25%2F2021&endTime=10%3A00&international=true&isMapSearch=false&itemsPerPage=200&latitude=40.735657&location=newark%2C%20nj&locationType=City&longitude=-74.1723667&maximumDistanceInMiles=50&region=NJ&sortType=RELEVANCE&startDate=09%2F22%2F2021&startTime=10%3A00')
time.sleep(10)

button = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('/us/en/car-rental/')

button.click()
```

but the code throws an error that the element can't be found.

Comment: Is page url public ? it could be in an iframe ?

Comment: also please share the error stack trace in text format here ?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to successfully identify the element by xpath:

```
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-testid='vehicle-card-link-box']")
```